# XML не принимает URL

Tags: php, xml, url

не могу в ХМЛ файлу добавить урл не получается вот сам код заранее спасибо

```
 $url_music = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/index.php?a=track&id=".$row['id'];
$sql =  mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO `test` (`name`)VALUES('$url_music')");
$date = $row['time'];
$date = str_replace(' ', 'T', $date);
$xml = simplexml_load_file($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/sitemap.xml");
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());
$newItem = $sxe->addChild("url");
$newItem->addChild("loc", "http://my-beybi.ru/index.php?a=track&id=30&name=art-avetisyan-anirakan-wwwergerru-2019mp3");

$newItem->addChild("lastmod", $date.'+03:00');
$newItem->addChild("changefreq", 'weekly');

$sxe->asXML($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/sitemap.xml");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML-символы нужно экранировать

```
$newItem->addChild(
    'loc',
    htmlspecialchars('http://my-beybi.ru/index.php?a=track&id=30&name=art-avetisyan-anirakan-wwwergerru-2019mp3')
);
```